# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandlerFactory

Tags: java, glassfish, omnifaces

When I publish an application on a server GlassFish 4.0, I am getting following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Factory 'javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerFactory' was not configured properly.     
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:273)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:5362)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:743)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5898)
... 44 more Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException:
Factory 'javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerFactory' was not configured properly.  
at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:330)
at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:236)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:435)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:214)
... 47 more Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException:
org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandlerFactory  
at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinder.java:710)
at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getImplementationInstance(FactoryFinder.java:572)
at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.access$500(FactoryFinder.java:140)     
at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:1120)
at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:379)     
at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:328)
... 50 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandlerFactory  
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1761)
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1611)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)  
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)  
at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinder.java:685)
... 55 more
```

How do I fix the error?

Comment: I think SO community won't be able to help at the present state of the question. Consider adding some details here, do some research like trying to deploy some simple application, etc.

Comment: The problem was solved after I added in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib several libraries - omnifaces-1.7.jar and primefaces-4.0.jar. Although these libraries were in classpath. Not sure about this decision optimal.

Comment: @VD' product/library/framework names like "GlassFish" are NOT code. Please do NOT format it as code either!

Comment: @BalusC yes its not code i understand, and not formatted as code even u can check my edit

Comment: @VD' That's because I already removed it. Check the edit history yourself. Just please stop formatting things like "Productname 1.2.3" as code. Those are *obviously* not code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandlerFactory

The `ClassNotFoundException` means that the mentioned class, or at least the JAR file containing the mentioned class, isn't present in the current runtime classpath.

When deployed as a WAR file, the webapp's runtime classpath covers among others the following paths:

- WAR's `/WEB-INF/classes` - for loose `.class` files (usually, IDE will do it automatically for source files in the `src` folder of the project).
- WAR's `/WEB-INF/lib` - for JAR files (if you're not using a dependency management framework such as Maven, then you need to manually drop JARs there).
- Server's `/lib` folder - for server-specific libraries, or for libraries which needs to be shared across all webapps (folder name depends on server used).
- JRE's (or JDK's) `/lib` and `/lib/ext` folders - never ever put anything there, unless you need to fix some bugs in JRE/JDK *itself*.

Usually, you only go for the first two options. Do it in the WAR only and not elsewhere.

The package name of the mentioned class, `org.omnifaces`, hints that it's part of [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org). You can download the JAR over there and according to its installation instructions, you need to drop it in `/WEB-INF/lib`.

---

As per your comment:

> *The problem was solved after I added in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib several libraries - omnifaces-1.7.jar and primefaces-4.0.jar. **Although these libraries were in classpath**. Not sure about this decision optimal.*

Sorry, but what you're stating there is just not true. The exception clearly tells that they were **not** in the classpath. `ClassNotFoundException`. Simple as that. At least not in the webapp's runtime classpath in any of the aforementioned paths. Most likely you incorrectly assumed the `%CLASSPATH%` environment variable, or the *Build Path* property of the project for the webapp's runtime classpath.